# InflateException when using chrisjenx CalligraphyLayoutInflater , android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate, calligraphy

Hi So in our project we are using calligraphy library , it works  with no issues but now in one of the activity i added it keeps crashing with the following stacktrace:

```
01-23 02:25:32.178 3654-3654/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example, PID: 3654
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.activities.MultipleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class com.example.components.WLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class com.example.components.WLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.activities.MultipleActivity.onCreate(MultipleActivity.java:62)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211) 
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20) 
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.activities.MultipleActivity.onCreate(MultipleActivity.java:62) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class TextView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
```

I checked a few answers but cant see anyone facing issue with textview.

I am attaching to calligraphy as follows in my activity

> ```
> @Override
> protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
>   super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
> }
> ```

The theme of the activity is as follows

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Compat.ActionBar.Dark.NoBackground" parent="AppTheme.Compat.ActionBar.Dark">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/alert_title</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray400</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/alert_button</item>
    </style>
```

I noticed studio giving  warning  for android:colorAccent and replace with "colorAccent" that  removed the warning  but the crash remained . Any clues  what  am I doing  wrong here ??

Comment: add java code of `multipleActivity.class`

Comment: Any luck with this @amIT?

Comment: was able to find a solution posting it as answer @David Argyle Thacker

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured  out the problem , Since the issue was happening in Textview as per the crash logs

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class TextView

**TLDR : dont use setbackground for TextView its bug prone (samsung), espcially if  its Vector drawable.**

I verified by removing the textview the crash stopped happening.The issue was i used to set background image for my textview and it was a SVG image and i have been appCompact library(v23).  Setting vector drawable is only supported via "app:srcCompat" or "setImageResource()" as the foolproof way to use vector drawable.

I read the this blog post to see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html I see previous supported Textview has now been striked out ,  which means its not stable and bug prone.

I removed the Vector drawable  from textview and added a another Imageview just below textview with the vector drawable using "src:compact", so that visually they still look same  i.e a Text view with background.

If  app size isnt a issue  you can  also use a png /jpg  resource and  avoid the creation of extra imageview in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 3.0.1

I have got the same issue and I have resolved finally Opening the `gradle.properties` and added following line:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```